# Submit webform via URL only?

Tags: url, http-post, url-parameters, forms, form-post

I'm not really sure this belongs here, so instead of downvoting just lemme know if so and I'll quickly move it on.

Anyway, there is a [website](http://www.torec.net/) that has a search page, that when hitting the search button it doesn't include the search query in the URL.

After searching for something, the page is redirected to [`ssearch.asp`](http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp), but as said, the query isn't there.

My question is if there is a way to submit the search values solely via URL.

I was wondering if there is a way to fake the search-submit button and post the search term 
via URL according to form field names.

The name of the input box is `search`, so I tried this URL: http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp?search=query, but it doesn't work, the server returns:

> server error.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a server-side solution, and actually nor for a HTML solution, I just want to be able to paste a plain old URL in my browsers address bar and be there.

Is this possible?

**Update**

This link doesn't work:
[http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp?search=dark&page=1](http://goo.gl/6KZ1t)

While this one does:
[http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp?search=dark&page=2](http://goo.gl/FG9H8)

Any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes servers conflate GET and POST parameters, as in PHP `$_REQUEST` hash. However, normally they are separate - and a server that expects its parameters in `multipart/form-data` might not look at URL at all. In such a case, as it seems to be here, you have to construct a POST request. On the client side you can do it through AJAX or through constructing and posting a form; on the server side, you can use `curl`, or a library. You did not say what you want to use it for (and where you want to use it), so you just get the general answer, I'm afraid.

EDIT: Here is the JavaScript semi-solution. You have to already be on some page (i.e. can't use it on _blank), and I'm not sure if it works on all browsers.

```
javascript:d=document;f=d.createElement("form");h=d.createElement("input");f.setAttribute("method","post");f.setAttribute("enctype","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");f.setAttribute("action","http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp");h.setAttribute("type","hidden");h.setAttribute("name","search");h.setAttribute("value","query");f.appendChild(h);d.body.appendChild(f);f.submit();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't have control of the server, nor of the client, I don't want to use any html, just simple plain old URL only that is pasted in the browsers address bar. Is this possible?

Comment: In a word - no. In several words, technically yes, using a javascript URL.

Comment: Can you please expand about the js url?

Comment: I believe he means you would paste this in your address bar: `javascript:var a=document.createElement("form");a.method="POST";a.action="http://www.torec.net/ssearch.asp?search=dark&page=2";var i=document.createElement("input");i.name="search";i.value="q";a.appendChild(input);a.submit();`

Comment: @MatthewDean: damn I'm slow... :P

Comment: @Amadan, lol, Chrome won't accept this length haha, I'll try via [goo.gl](http://goo.gl)...

Comment: Chrome will accept it, because I just did it in Chrome. The most limited is IE, at ~2000 characters; most other accept 64KB URLs.

Comment: Did you note the "must have a page loaded"? Also, it's a hack, therefore "technically yes". If you have any other solution, it'll be better. As you note, it seems they do allow you 2nd page; and 1st page is broken even in their own interface (you can't go back to page 1).

Comment: You already answered my question, anyway, per my issue: what I'm trying to achieve is add that site to google's search engines so that I can write 'torec.net' in the address bar, and hit tab for search, I tried to replace `query` with `%s` in your query, added to chrome search engines but that didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It is not possible to create a link directly to the first page. However, you can easily send a user to the first page by by creating a form:

```
<form id="postForm" method="post" action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="q">
</form>
```

And then submitting the form whenever the user clicks a psuedo-link:

```
document.getElementById("postForm").submit();
```

This can also be done by typing JavaScript code into the address bar:

`javascript:a=document.createElement("form");a.method="POST";a.action="http://www.torec.net/‌​ssearch.asp?search=dark&page=2";i=document.createElement("input");i.name="search";i.value="q";a.appendChild(inpu‌​t);a.submit();`

Comment: The only means I can send users to is plain URL, if that's not possible then the answer is NO...

Comment: @Shimmy It is possible to send users to the first page - all they have to do is visit your web page. Read my revised answer.